# Callback execution only on last in stack

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I've set it up like this,

```
var elements = $('#one, $two, #three, #four, #six');

var _temp = 0;
elements.hide(0, function(){
    /* by default, the callback will be performed to
       every single element in stack */

    _temp++; // increment temporary cache

    // perform actual callback only on last in list
    if (_temp == elements.length) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

but it feels wrong, because if I'd want to do the same for another callback 241 lines below, I'd have to reset `_temp` and well, global variables are just messy.

How could I simplify this?

Comment: `hide` doesn't have a callback as the first argument. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Woops, wasn't copy-pasting from script, forgot the 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way is to use a closure:

```
var elements = $('#one, $two, #three, #four, #six');

elements.hide(0, (function(){
    var _temp = 0;
    return function(){
        _temp++; // increment temporary cache

        // perform actual callback only on last in list
        if (_temp == elements.length) {
            // do stuff
        }
    };
})());
```

If you want to use this pattern more often you could create a function which returns a callback.

Also note that [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) has a duration as first argument.

Comment: Though, may I suggest that if the same callback is going to be used somewhere else in the document, that it might be more proper to cache the returned function of the self-calling function, then pass that into `elements.hide()` instead?

Comment: If the same callback with the same variable/counter is going to be used more then once: yes, indeed. Otherwise a closure wouldn't make much sense, as `_temp` can be replaced by an in-function variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a static variable in your function.

Comment: Your statement should be a comment but not the answer.

Comment: Sorry for that. It was my first time and i was not even sure what language is that.

Comment: And i'm trying to get 15 reputation to be able to give a +1 to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another way without temporary variable, it may be a little less readable for some, and forces you to store your selection inside a variable, but:

```
elements.hide(0, function(){
    // if last callback (compare raw DOMElements, because jQuery object aren't somehow similar)
    if ($(this)[0] === elements.last()[0]) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Narrows down some lines, and does the trick.